# How to delete a DIV block in all HTML files of a directory tree?

Tags: regex, replace

I have a DIV block which I want to remove from all HTML files.

```
    <div id="mainTopSearch">
         <form method="post" action="/search">
                <input name="query" id="top_query" type="text" class="input placeholder" placeholder="Search">
            <input type="hidden" name="sec" value="Marketing/Products">
        </form>
    </div>
```

I am using Notepad++. I tried to copy paste the DIV from `<div>` to `</div>` and find it.
The result is the `<div id="mainTopSearch">` only can be pasted.

So what is the solution for me to remove the whole DIV block?

What is your recommended editor beside Notepad++ and Sublime Text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shareware editor UltraEdit supports multi-line find and replace in current file, current selection, all open files, or all files of a directory or even a directory tree.

But if you are not 100% sure that in all files this block is present with the same bytes, it is better to use a Perl regular expression Replace in Files for this task which I think the other editors support, too.

The Perl regular expression search string is:

```
[\t ]*<div id="mainTopSearch">\s*<form method[\s\S]+?</form>\s*</div>[\t ]*\r?\n?
```

The replace string is an empty string (nothing).

Explanation for the not fixed strings in the search expression:

`[\t ]*` ... tabs or spaces 0 or more times, most likely found at beginning of line with starting div tag.

`\s*` ... any whitespace character including carriage return and line-feed 0 or more times.

`[\s\S]+?` ... any character including carriage return and line-feed 1 or more times non-greedy. Non-greedy means stop on first `</form>` and not on last `</form>` making this search expression still a positive match.

`\r?\n?` ... 0 or 1 times a carriage return and 0 or 1 times a line-feed.